# Gente, eu estou precisando gerar um json array, porém, o meu código só esta retornando o json do jeito que vou deixar pra voces verem

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express.js, fs

const fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");
const app = express();

const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

//rotas

app.get("/", function(req,res){
res.render("formulario")
})

app.post("/add",function(req, res){

```
const data = {
    quantidadeBeneficiarios: `${req.body.quantidadeBeneficiarios}`,
    idadeBeneficiarios:`${req.body.idadeBeneficiarios}`,
    nomeBeneficiario:`${req.body.nomeBeneficiario}`,
    registroPlano:`${req.body.registroPlano}`
    
    
    }
```

//                                                             [aqui eu mostr quais dadso quero que passe pro json]
fs.appendFile('./beneficiarios.json', JSON.stringify(data, [quantidadeBeneficiarios, idadeBeneficiarios, nomeBeneficiario, registroPlano],2), 'utf-8', (error, result)=>{
if (error){
console.error(error)
}
return;
})
//
// const dataString =  JSON.stringify(data, [quantidadeBeneficiarios, idadeBeneficiarios, nomeBeneficiario, registroPlano], 4)
// fs.appendFileSync('./beneficiarios.json',dataString, 'utf-8')

})

//servidor
app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Servidor rodando na url: http://localhost:3000");
})

o Desta maneira, da erro "quantidadeBeneficiarios is not defined"

e substituindo os argumentos da linha 32, colcoando "null" ao inves de [...] ele retorna os json so que da seguinte maneira:
(vou usar um só apenas para facilitar a escrita e o entendimento, mas ele registra todos os arumentos
{
quantidadeBeneficiarios: "3"
}
{
quantidadeBeneficiarios: "2"
}

Formato que eu preciso:
[
{
quantidadeBeneficiarios: "3"
},
{
quantidadeBeneficiarios: "2"
}
]

Answer (score -2):

quantidadeBeneficiarios, idadeBeneficiarios, nomeBeneficiario e registroPlano não estão referenciadas corretamente.

Além disso, se você quiser apenas imprimir algumas propriedades específicas, vc deve passar um array com os nomes dessas propriedades, veja o exemplo abaixo:

Deveria ser...

```
JSON.stringify(data, ["quantidadeBeneficiarios", "idadeBeneficiarios", "nomeBeneficiario", "registroPlano"],2)
```

Mas se quiser imprimir todas as propriedades...
JSON.stringify(data, null,2)